# Rotation on Custom file relative-to wildlfy logging does'nt work

Tags: logging, rotation, wildfly-9

I have a domain cluster wildlfy and on each node i have 2 or more VM on each node i want write all servers node on same file in domain/log to make it work :

```
  <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_BACKEND" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN_BACKEND"/>
                </formatter>
                                    <rotate-size value="5k"/>
                <max-backup-index value="10"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
                 <file relative-to="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>

            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_PORTAL" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN_PORTAL"/>
                </formatter>
                                    <rotate-size value="5k"/>
                <max-backup-index value="10"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
                 <file relative-to="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>

            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN_SERVER"/>
                </formatter>
                <rotate-size value="5k"/>
                <max-backup-index value="10"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
                <file relative-to="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="AOF_ERRORS_FILE">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="errors.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="AOF_PERFS_FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="aof_perfs.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.security">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.web.security">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.real.aof.interceptor.PerformanceInterceptor" use-parent-handlers="false">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="AOF_PERFS_FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.real.aof" use-parent-handlers="false">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_BACKEND"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.real.portal" use-parent-handlers="false">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_PORTAL"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jgroups.protocols.UDP">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_PORTAL"/>
                    <handler name="FILE_BACKEND"/>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                    <handler name="AOF_ERRORS_FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="PATTERN_PORTAL">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="PORTAL                 %d{mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="PATTERN_SERVER">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="SERVER  ${jboss.server.name} %d{mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="PATTERN_BACKEND">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="BACKEND ${jboss.server.name} %d{mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
```

and in host.xml on each node :

```
 <servers>
    <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
     <paths>
    <path name="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="c:/dev/servers/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/domain/log" />

    </server>
   ....
</servers>
```

the problem is : rotation not working... if i change custom.jboss.log.dir by jboss.server.log.dir server.log will be created on each server (vm) and the rotation will be effectued but if i redirect all logs on One in domain/log all logs are written in one file but the rotation does'nt work, i try with periodic-handler too but it does not work too

any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried just using one file writing to the `server.log` at a time? It looks like you have 3 handlers writing to the same file which could be an issue.

Comment: one handler is ok but i have 2 applications and server log, i need all 3 logs wrote into the same file with specifiq patterns so i created 3 handler with for each one pattern and then each one write log in same file (indeed if i have one or two or more jvm into host.xml all logs are writen in one file ... log agreggation)

Comment: do you think i can use several patterns in one handler ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use different handlers to write to the same file. You could see all kinds of different issues with that. What logging framework do you use in your application?

Comment: we use wildlfy logging file only neither log4j or slf4j or logback i have to find a solution with server , we want log several applications and server log to the same file it is the customer requirement... to aggregate 4 cluster files logs

Comment: What I meant by logging framework was how you do logging in your application. If you use jboss-logging, slf4j or log4j you could use MDC to achieve this. You can't write to the same file with ANY log manager. That will always be a problem.

Comment: Yes i know but it is the requirements. thank you for your help we will propose a log aggregator like ELK stack (KIBANA; elastic search and logstash)